# Is 'silently' placed correctly?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-choice

I have written this:

Fiona silently takes in the sight of the city.

Is 'silently' placed correctly? Could I also place it at the end of the sentence?

Fiona takes in the sight of the city silently.

Comment: I think I might have put _silently_ first but differences here are fairly marginal.

Answer (score 3):

You can put *silently* in 3 different places in this sentence:

- At the beginning:

> **Silently**, Fiona takes in the sight of the city.

- In the middle (like you did):

> Fiona **silently** takes in the sight of the city.

- At the end:

> Fiona takes in the sight of the city **silently**.

There are no big differences in the meaning of these 3 sentences, but *personally* I would use the second one or at least the first one.

Check out this explanation from Cambridge dictionary on "how to order an adjective": [Order of adjectives](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adjectives-order)

Comment: I think _silently_ is an adverb, not an adjective.

Comment: I would say there are some significant differences in the different expressions. For example, the third example places much more emphasis on the fact that she is doing it silently.

Answer (score 0):

Putting "silently" at the end of the sentence is perfectly fine but most people would put it before "takes".

Modifiers usually come before the word being modified, so "Fiona silently takes in the sight of the city" sounds more *natural*.